# How can i check validation from parent component to nested child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reactive form and the submit button is in the grand parent component. Now I want to check the validation status of my child component using view child or any other method. I have no idea how can I do that. Please help me to solve this impossible issue according to me.

**Child Component**

```
<form [formGroup]="headerForm"></form>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<app-header
  [countries]="countries$ | async"
  [products]="products$ | async"
  [statuses]="statuses$ | async"
  (headerChanged)="getHeaderInformation($event)"
>
</app-header>
```

**Grand Parent Componenet**

```
  <app-header-shell
    (headerShellChanged)="updateRegulatoryAffairShell($event)"
  ></app-header-shell>
```

Here I am passing data between components using `@Output` but unable to check validation. Please help

```
 @Output() headerShellChanged = new EventEmitter<IRegulatoryAffair>();

  getHeaderInformation(regulatoryAffair: IRegulatoryAffair) {
    this.headerShellChanged.emit(regulatoryAffair);
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean check validation, is the child component part of the form ?

Comment: No child component is different, I just need true false response from the child component to grand parent component

Comment: Like sharing data between components, but in my case I want to check validations

Answer (score 0):

Give the component a template Ref:

```
<app-header
  #appHeaderComponent
  [countries]="countries$ | async"
  [products]="products$ | async"
  [statuses]="statuses$ | async"
  (headerChanged)="getHeaderInformation($event)"
>
</app-header>
```

then in grandParent component declare the entire component as a ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('appHeaderComponent') appHeaderComponent: AppHeaderComponent
```

Now you have access to the entire component and can read any property/call any method:

```
this.appHeaderComponent.headerForm.markAllAsTouched();
this.appHeaderComponent.headerForm.valid ? this.doSubmit() : return;
```

As a further example you can also read and control the state of individual form controls:

```
this.appHeaderComponent.headerForm.get('myControl').setValidators([Validators.required]);
```